# C++ std::regex_match with multiple groups

Tags: c++, regex, match

I trying to use C++ `std::regex_math` for the first time on some strings like these, and I trying to extract A, e, guard, action and B when available.

```
hsm::state<A>  = hsm::state<B>
hsm::state<A> + hsm::event<e> = hsm::state<B>
hsm::state<A> [guard] = hsm::state<B>
hsm::state<A> / action = hsm::state<B>
hsm::state<A> + hsm::event<e> [guard] = hsm::state<B>
hsm::state<A> [guard] / action = hsm::state<B>
hsm::state<A> + hsm::event<e> [guard] / action = hsm::state<B>
```

So I can generate some plantuml state diagrams later.
Usually, I do it with some split/trim but I decide to learn regex... So far I have come to this the code below.

It's almost correct. It remains event, guard, and action which resist me. I did not succeed to remove undesired chars

```
   m[2]: event : [ + hsm::event<e>]
   m[3]: guard : [ [guard]]
   m[4]: action: [ / action ]
```

Here, " + ", '[' and ']', and " / ".

Any tips to go further ?

Regards,

Here my last attempt:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::regex re{"(.*hsm::state<.[^>]*>)(.*hsm::event<.[^>]*>)?(.*\\[.[^>]*\\])?(.*/.[^=]*)?.*(hsm::state<.[^>]*>).*"};

    ifstream file(argv[1]);

    for (std::string line; getline(file, line);) {
        cout << "[" << line << "]" << endl;
        std::smatch match;

        if (std::regex_match(line, match, re)) {
            const char* names[] = {"", "source", "event ", "guard ", "action", "target", "", "", ""};
            for (size_t i = 1; i < match.size(); ++i) {
                cout << "   m[" << i << "]: " << names[i] << ": [" << match[i] << "]" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start simple on e.g. https://regex101.com, which will easily help you debug regular expressions. Then expand the expression until you can parse out the data you need.

Comment: With the above in mind for testing and debugging your regular expressions, I would recommend that you don't try to handle all the different inputs in a single regular expression. Instead have some kind of recognizer which calls a function that parsers one specific input-type.

Comment: Or for even simpler handling, multiple simple passes over the input, each pass extract only one single part (one for `A`, one for `e`, etc.). Then the regular expressions becomes *very* simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to avoid mulitple passes, this is mostly what I have done until now.

So I came up with this. Splitting RE for each part, some non-capturing groups, and lot of space discard (instead of a global std::remove_if before parsing).

If there is better, I took it (no validation for composed group like + hsm::event<...>)

```
    std::regex re{// source
              R"(hsm::state<(\w*)>\s*)"
              // optional event
              R"(\+?\s*)"
              R"((?:hsm::event<)?(\w*)(?:>)?\s*)"
              // optional guard
              R"(\[?(\w*)\]?\s*)"
              // optional action
              R"(/?\s*)"
              R"((\w*)\s*)"
              // target
              R"(=\s*)"
              R"(hsm::state<(\w*)>)"};
```

Comment: Note that "surrounders" doesn't need to match with proposal regex i.e `[guard` (without `]`)  would match.

Comment: Yes, and this is probably wwhy I do not like to much this solution. May be as suggested @someprogrammerdude, use multiple regex, to add some validations (like [ and ] be present)
`std::regex re_source(R"(hsm::state<(\w*)>.*=)");`
`std::regex re_target(R"(=\s*hsm::state<(\w*)>)");`
`std::regex re_event(R"(\+\s*hsm::event<(\w*)>)");`
`std::regex re_guard(R"(\[(\w*)\])");`


Sorry I did not succeed to format code in the comment :(